# Doing String length on SQL Loader input field

Tags: oracle, sql-loader

I'm reading data from a fixed length text file and loading into a table with fixed length processing.

I want to  check the input line length so that i'd discard the records that are not matching the fixed length and logging them into an Error Table.

Example

Load into Input_Log table if line is meeting the specified length
Load into Input_Error_Log table if the input line length is less than or greater than the fixed line length.

Comment: In other words, you will load the entire line into one of 2 tables depending on if it meets the length requirement?  No parsing of the correct-sized line into columns?  Perhaps show some real data with before/after examples to help us understand.

Answer (score 0):

I believe you would be better served by bulk loading your data into a staging table, then load into the production table from there via a stored procedure where you can apply rules via normal PL/SQL & DML to your heart's content.  This is a typical best practice anyway.

sqlldr isn't really the tool to get too complicated in, even if you could do what you want.  Maintainability and restart-ability become more complicated when you add complexity to a tool that's really designed for bulk loading.  Add the complexity to a proper program.

Let us know what you come up with.

Comment: There was no solution in sqlldr i used java to pre process the file. coming to loading data into staging table, what if the data exceeds the staging table column limits ?

Comment: In the staging table make the column sizes larger than needed.  Length tests will be in your java code then.